# Why is apple swift book initializing an int array like Int[] when it only allows [Int] in playground?

Tags: arrays, swift

How come the apple swift book shows functions like

```
func something(list: Int[]) {
    //do something
}
```

when the proper initialization is

```
[Int]
```

?

When I tried it the first play playground complains and offers a suggestion to correct it to the second way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array shorthand syntax changed over time, so you're probably referring to an old version of the book.

Specifically it changed on the beta release of July 07, 2014. Here's the relevant bit of the changelog:

> [Array Type Shorthand Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_172) is now written as `[SomeType]` rather than `SomeType[]`.

([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH40-XID_1655))

You can find the latest version of the book here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/

Comment: Yeah that's the one I'm reading and it totally refers to it as Int[]. Also, how come I had to download the beta of xcode instead of just upgrading my current version? Namely for Watch development as well.

Comment: This copy is updated: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_172

Are you sure you've upgraded the iBook one?

Comment: Yes that's the one I've downloaded and am reading in iBooks. Book 1, Swift Programming Series. I don't see anywhere an option to upgrade it. It says published Jun 2, 2014. I can see it says Updated Oct 16th 2014, But I can see clearly here on Page 14 the use of Int[]

Answer (score 0):

Swift used to define arrays like `Int[]` but it was changed in one of the betas to be the form `[Int]`. Make sure you have the latest version of the Swift book. If you do, you should file a [feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) with Apple because that is no longer correct.